# Why I couldn't hear anything when using time()?

Tags: python, datetime, audio

I have initialized everything (audio, time, etc...). But when I used time, I heard no sound.

How can I fix it?

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime

friday = pyttsx3.init()
voice = friday.getProperty("voices")
friday.setProperty('voice', voice[1].id)

def speak(audio):
    friday.say(audio)
    friday.runAndWait()

def time():
    Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%p')
    speak(time)
time()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have made a small mistake in naming variables.

> def time():
> **Time** = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%p')
> speak(**time**)

Aren't they supposed to be the same variable.

Comment: If this is the problem, the question should be closed as a typo, not answered.